# How do I display page content when browser navigates to an file download?

Tags: javascript, http, browser

I have a page that takes a URL as an argument and immediately navigates to that URL. This URL may go to another webpage, or it can be a file to download. I don't know ahead of time where the URL will go.

If the URL is a download link, I want to display a message to the user. This can be either by making a div visible, or by any other mechanism. Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

```
<html><head><script>

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var url = urlParams.get("url");
window.top.location.href = url;

// How do I execute the following lines only if url is pointing to a download?
{
  var contentEl = document.getElementById('page-content');
  contentEl.style.display='block';
}

</script>
</head>
<body><div id='page-content' style='display: none;'>You may close this page</div></body>
</html>
```

The only thing I have thought of so far is to add a timeout, but it seems pretty lame. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try in this way ,before navigate to the url you can check what file extensions of the url is. so now you can open url if the file extensions is some thing like '.html','.jsp' and so on. Display message if the url extensions is '.zip','.docx'...

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var url = urlParams.get("url");
//check extensions here
if(isFileExtensionsLikeHtmlOrJsp(url)){
    window.top.location.href = url;
}else{
    //display message
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately in this case, correct extensions may not always be present.